# VBA - Updating a ProcessBar from module - Error 800100007

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I want to call a process bar from the module *main* and update the bar from *main*.
I have in my *UserForm1*:

- *Label5* with the max value
- *Label2* with the current value
- *ProgressBar1* with the current value from 0 to 100

the module code is:

```
Public Sub main()
    Dim i, max, k, dummy As Long
    Dim myUserForm As UserForm1

    Set myUserForm = New UserForm1
    max = 100
    myUserForm.Label5 = max
    myUserForm.Label2 = 0
    myUserForm.Show
    For i = 1 To max
        myUserForm.UpdateStatus i
        For k = 1 To 10000              'loop for time-consuming
            dummy = Sqr(k)
        Next
    Next
    Unload myUserForm
End Sub
```

The code in *UserForm1* is:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub UpdateStatus(i)
    Me.Label2 = i
    Me.ProgressBar1 = i
    DoEvents
End Sub
```

The *UserForm1* shows up once and then I get in *main* at *myUserForm.UpdateStatus i* the error *800100007*. I am using VBA Word. How can I make it work?

Comment: variable i is private in module. public it before sub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change how you display the form:

```
myUserForm.Show vbModeless
```

Currently, the loop is not executing until you close the form at which point the form is not available and an error is generated.